# How to preserve state in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, scope

When using a class, I can preserve a state using a property:

```
class Hello:

    def __init__(self):
        self.hello = 1

    def add_one(self):
        if self.hello < 3:
            self.hello += 1
        else:
            self.hello = 1

h = Hello()
for _ in range(5):
    h.add_one()
    print(h.hello)

# output
2
3
1
2
3
```

In between calls to `h.add_one()`, the state is preserved in `h.hello`.

**Is there an equivalent mechanism in functions?** Something along the lines of

```
def add_one():
    a_special_kind_of_variable_which_is_not_reinitialized hello
    if hello_is_not_initialized:
        hello = 1
    if hello < 3:
        hello += 1
    else:
        hello = 1
    return hello

for _ in range(5):
    print(add_one())

# same output as above
```

- Using a global variable would be a solution but I would like to avoid that.
- Passing back the returned value to the function to force the state is another option, but I am hoping for a way to keep the state within the function without external dependencies.

Comment: A function is an object. You can assign attributes to it. Or just use a global.

Comment: @khelwood how can you assign an attribute to a function?

Comment: @Gsk `my_func.my_attr = 42`

Comment: @WoJ This is sort of the important distinction between a class and a function. A simple function *should* usually be stateless. There may be some cases where keeping state is desired, but in the general case it's not.

Comment: Why do you want to do this rather than use a class?

Comment: One could (but shouldn't) hack the mutable default argument for such purposes

Comment: @Chris_Rands: *Why do you want to do this rather than use a class?* I am not experienced enough to answer, actually. I had a class, simplified it to a function and then realized that it would be good to keep state for some elements. One way was to go back to a class but this is an opportunity to learn whether there are similar mechanisms in functions. But you are right - going for a class is probably the right way after all, I was under the impression that a class should be used for greater things :) (inheritance, several objects, ...)

Comment: If separate instances of the function is required (e.g. tracking different calls from different sources), a class would definitely be the way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python does not have C-style static variables. However, you can simulate them with closures.

```
def make_add_one():
    x = 0
    def _():
        nonlocal x
        if x < 3:
           x += 1
        else:
            x = 1
        return x
    return _

add_one = make_add_one()

for _ in range(5):
    print(add_one())
```

---

There is a duality between objects (data with functions) and closures (functions with data); compare to the [class defined by Carcigenicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57996136/1126841) (slightly modified):

```
class AddOne:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hello = 0

    def __call__(self):
        if self.hello < 3:
            self.hello += 1
        else:
            self.hello = 1
        return self.hello

add_one = AddOne()
for _ in range(5):
    print(add_one())
```

One can see the following correspondences:

- class `AddOne` ↔ outer function `make_add_one`
- instance `AddOne()` ↔ inner function `make_add_one()`
- instance attribute `AddOne().hello` ↔ non-local variable `hello` inside `make_add_one`

Answer (score 2):

You could just make instances of the class function-like by implementing [`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__):

```
class Hello:

    def __init__(self):
        self.hello = 1

    def __call__(self):
        if self.hello < 3:
            self.hello += 1
        else:
            self.hello = 1

h = Hello()
h()  # Works now
```

Although, this only changes calling syntax. This is still basically your first class example.

Having "instances of functions" is probably a safer setup anyways though. It's easier to test a function that doesn't have a permanent persistent state from other operations that were done on it. To test it cleanly, you simply need to create a new instance, whereas with a "global function", it could have accidentally been effected by other stuff you did to it previously.

Answer (score 1):

You can add attributes to functions since they are objects:

```
def add_one():
    if not hasattr(add_one, 'hello'):
        add_one.hello = 1
    if add_one.hello < 3:
        add_one.hello += 1
    else:
        add_one.hello = 1
    return add_one.hello


for _ in range(5):
    print(add_one())
```

Outputs

```
2
3
1
2 
3
```

Comment: A slight complication is that `add_one` doesn't necessarily refer to the function itself; it refers to whatever the global name `add_one` refers to, which can be changed.

Comment: @chepner correct. Can be hacked with frames but I really don't think it's worth it

Comment: It's not even that hard. `foo = add_one; def add_one(): ...`. Now `foo` is the function you originally defined, but inside that function it tries to access `add_one.hello` which no longer exists (or rather, gets recreated, but on an entirely different function object). Do `add_one = []` instead, and `foo` breaks.

Comment: Really, the function attribute is just a global variable in disguise.